# CMake: Get version from multiline text file

Tags: cmake, versioning

I have a file `version.txt`

```
VERSION_MAJOR 1
VERSION_MINOR 1
VERSION_PATCH 3
```

I want to use cmake to add a definition for major, minor and patch.

I've tries using

```
file(STRING "version.txt" myvar)
```

but this just puts the whole file in `myvar`.

How do I get the numbers?

Comment: Have you tried using a [regex](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-match)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: Read build number from file to set a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737433/cmake-read-build-number-from-file-to-set-a-variable)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your use of `file` is incorrect, you want to use [`READ`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#read) in order to read the contents of the file into a variable.

```
file(READ "version.txt" ver)
```

Once you have the file's contents into a variable, you can then use [`REGEX MATCH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-match) with a capture group, and access the capture group using [`CMAKE_MATCH_N`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MATCH_n.html)

**[`REGEX MATCH:`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-match)**

Create a regular expression with a capture group which will capture the numbers following `"VERSION_MAJOR"`:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
```

Note that if the regex matches the input variable, the entire match will be stored in the output variable. However, we don't want the entire match (as that includes the string `"VERSION_MAJOR"`), so I've just used a variable name `_` as the output variable, which, by convention, tells the user I am not interested in this variable

**[`CMAKE_MATCH_N:`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MATCH_n.html)**

If the match is successful, then the capture groups are available in `CMAKE_MATCH_N`. In this instance there is only one capture group, so we want to use `CMAKE_MATCH_1`

```
set(ver_major ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
```

At this point `ver_major` contains just the major version no.

You can then repeat this for the other version components.

**Full example below:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

file(READ "version.txt" ver)

string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MAJOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(ver_major ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_MINOR ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(ver_minor ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

string(REGEX MATCH "VERSION_PATCH ([0-9]*)" _ ${ver})
set(ver_patch ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})

message("version: ${ver_major}.${ver_minor}.${ver_patch}")
```

**Output:**

```
$ cmake .
version: 1.1.3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp
```

For production code you would obviously want to make the cmake script more robust by checking whether the match was successful, and emitting an error if not.

Comment: That is super helpful. I was trying to do the regex in the same line as the file that didn't work. What I found to also work was to turn it all into  a list then index into 1, 3, and 5